# не добавился таб для работы с npm в webstorm

Tags: node.js, npm, webstorm

перешел с phpstorm и там эта вкладка добавлена была автоматически. Как добавить ее теперь и тут?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не знаю, о каком табе идет речь... Чтобы открыть [NPM Tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.2/npm-tool-window.html), кликните правой кнопкой на `package.json`, выберите `Show NPM scripts`